# How to solve these trigonometry system of equations?

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations

$\sin2x-a\sin\left(x-b\right)=\sin\left(x+y\right)$

$\sin2y-a\sin\left(y-b\right)=\sin\left(x+y\right)$

$a$ and $b$ are constant values,

$x$ and $y$ are unknown variables .

first substract them:

$2\cos\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)\cos\left(x+y\right)=a\cos\left(\frac{x+y}{2}-b\right)$

and adding them:

$2\left(1-\cos^{2}\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)\right)\sin\left(x+y\right)+a\sin\left(\frac{x+y}{2}-b\right)\cos\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)=0$

now multiply this equation above with $\cos^{2}\left(x+y\right)$, we get :

$2\left(\cos^{2}\left(x+y\right)-\cos^{2}\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)\cos^{2}\left(x+y\right)\right)\sin\left(x+y\right)+a\sin\left(\frac{x+y}{2}-b\right)\cos\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)\cos^{2}\left(x+y\right)=0$

now replace $2\cos\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)\cos\left(x+y\right)$ with $a\cos\left(\frac{x+y}{2}-b\right)$,we get :

$\left(2\cos^{2}\left(x+y\right)-\frac{1}{2}a^{2}\cos^{2}\left(\frac{x+y}{2}-b\right)\right)\sin\left(x+y\right)+\frac{1}{4}a^{2}\sin\left(x+y-2b\right)\cos\left(x+y\right)=0$

now we have only one variable in this equation ,which is $\frac{x+y}{2}$ .

then we can simplify it down to :

$8z^{3}-8z+a^{2}z+a^{2}\sin2b=0$

here $z=\sin\left(x+y\right)$

now solving this equation is trival, thus problem solved .

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: You have made a mistake while subtracting. It should be $\cos(x+y)=a\cos{(\frac{x+y}{2}-b)}$